# Detect overflow in input field

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to detect with jQuery if an input field starts to overflow? Or do I have to do this with `<textarea></textarea>` or something like that?

I already tried it with:

```
<input id="inputField" type="text" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input").keyup(function() {
            var maxLen = 3
            var box = document.getElementById('inputField')[0];
            if (box.value.length > maxLen - 1) {
                alert('stop');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn't really work.

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById('inputField')` (without the brackets at the end)!

Comment: It is not an array of elements :O

Comment: since you are using jQuery already may i recommend using jquery.validation which will allow you to set an element to have a max length and a min length.  Also a RegEx to keep the data clean.

Comment: Are you detecting character overrun or visual/layout overrun?

Comment: But is there a way to detect an overflow like I asked in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a couple of changes, but the important one is to remove the `[0]` from the `getElementById` call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").keyup(function() {
        var maxLen = 3;
        var box = document.getElementById('inputField');
        if (box.value.length >= maxLen) {
            alert('stop');
        }
    });
});
```

You can also lean on [pure HTML validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input):

```
<input id="inputField" type="text" maxlength="3" />
```

And HTML5 validation attributes...

```
<input id="inputField" type="text" maxlength="3" required />
```

If you just want the text field to expand as someone types, you can use this:

Given this input:

```
<p>Test Input: <input type="text" size="4" name="test" id="test" /></p>
```

This will expand as you type:

```
var testInput = document.getElementById('test');

var setLength = function () {
    testInput.size = testInput.value.length ? testInput.value.length : 1;
};

testInput.onkeyup = setLength;

setLength();
```

Comment: But is there also a way to detect an overflow of an input?

Comment: The JavaScript / jQuery solution you wrote will do that - with the adjustments above. The HTML attribute will generally prevent the additional characters.

Comment: But in my case the size of the input box will be changed so that the number of characters has to be dynamically

Comment: You could use `document.getElementById('inputField').maxlength = 5;` (where 5 is any number you like).

Comment: I want to change the size of the maxlength depending on the length of the input.

Comment: Here is an example where I update the maxlength based on whatever you enter in the length field: http://jsfiddle.net/eZCee/ - if you want to increase the maxlength when people type, you aren't restricting the input and you might need to tell me the story about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay, it is really close to that what I am searching for. Only one thing. The maximum number of characters has to be detected automatically. Let's say an input field has a width of 50px and I need the maximum number of characters until the field is full. But the width is changing all the time. So the 3 may not be static, but must be detected. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Do you want to increase the size of the text box as more text is entered? If so - I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to use jquery for this, if your purpose is to limit the user input. you can also use:

```
<input maxlength="number">
```

Read about it on [this W3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)

If you do have to use jQuery you could do something like this:

```
$('input#input_amount').keyup(function () {
        $(this).val(function (i, val) {

            if (val.length>3){
                alert('stop');
            };
            return val;
        });
    });
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/BkZcq/

I've edited this answer (see comments):

```
$('input#input_amount').keyup(function () {
        $(this).val(function (i, val) {

            if (val.length>3){
                $(this).attr("size", val.length +1);
            };
            return val;
        });
    });
```

Comment: I think the code that I posted is a little bit confusing. In my case the size of the input field will be changed. So the number of characters has to be dynamically because I don't want that the input field has an overflow.

Comment: So you want to change the size of the input depending on the length of the input?

Comment: Okay, it is really close to that what I am searching for. Only one thing. The maximum number of characters has to be detected automatically. Let's say an input field has a width of 50px and I need the maximum number of characters until the field is full. But the width is changing all the time. So the 3 may not be static, but must be determined. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I can see what you mean, but the width of all the input characters is depending on you font settings. Since that is not measurable in px, % or even em's (because it also depends on your font-family and weight), and has to be compared to the exact size of the input, i am guessing this can not be achieved in the dynamic way you want it. So I think it comes down to tweaking and fine-tuning like this:http://jsfiddle.net/BkZcq/3/